# [error]cannot find -lpthread collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw

While trying to compile any `c++` program I am getting this error says.

`C:\Users\Friends\Documents>g++ default.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I just installed latest version of all `basic packages` from `MinGW Installer`. 
What should I do?

Comment: The error message suggests you should install the phtread library... But I honestly don't know... There's this package https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libpth-dev that you could install with apt-get install libpth-dev. Of course, at your own risk :). PD: I realize you're working on windows... Try and search for the same library in the package installer that came with your compiler collection.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan He's on *windows* platform. Maybe there is *pthread* package on mingw32 list.

Comment: @BiagioFesta, yep, just saw the C:\Users bit. The MingGW installer should have what he needs, right?.

Comment: Sorry for the spam but according to this http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library there's no pthreads for windows. The link suggests that you try http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32... If you're using c++ you can go c++11 and use the <threads> header that it's actually quite awesome.